# what is the meaning of 'if remote' in the following context?

Tags: word-usage, meaning, phrase-meaning, word-meaning

However, S.B. Chaudhuri observes, the revolt
was “the first combined attempt of many classes of people
to challenge a foreign power. This is a real, **if remote**,
approach to the freedom movement of India of a later age”

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The meaning is similar to [definition 3 at wiktionary:](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/remote#English)

> (*especially with respect to likelihood*) Slight.
> *They have a very **remote** chance of winning.*
> *You have a **remote** resemblance to my grandmother.*

So the sentence means that the revolt was foreshadowing the later Indian freedom movement. But the usage is awkward and not really idiomatic to my ear; "a remote approach" doesn't sound right. Perhaps I would have used "a slightly similar approach."

Answer (score 0):

> This is a real, if remote, approach to the freedom movement of India of a later age.

From [Cambridge Dictionary](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/remote),

> remote adjective (SLIGHT)

> a remote possibility

Your example hence means this is a real approach to the freedom movement of India of a later age even if it could be a *slight* approach.
From the context, we could also use *light* instead of *slight*.
[Ngram](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=slight+approach%2C+light+approach&year_start=1800&year_end=2019&corpus=26&smoothing=3)